# Generate a token from string and check it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, hash

I have a form for many product types. Each type is loaded by one `select` option.

Something like this:

```
<select name="name">
  <option value="product_1"> product one </option>
  <option value="product_2"> product two </option>
</select>
```

> Each product type have different inputs.
>   When `select` changes is triggered one ajax request for load refered `inputs`.

To make data validation in *backend*, i have to use the `option` value for know the submited product type.

Well, now the **vulnerability**:

1. user select and fill some product type
2. user intentionally change the current value of `option` tag (on browser) for **another valid value**
3. user send these inconsistent data for server

Obviously, isn't impossible to validate this but is kind of boring.

To make it easy, for each product type i put one `input[type=hidden]` with a "token" (hash) as `value` attribute.

Actually, the "token" is nothing more than (workaround) `Hash::make( $selected_option_value )`

> [See Hashing on Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing).

Now, when a product is submitted just check it `Hash::check( $selected_option_value, $selected_option_value_hash)` if true i have "sure" about product type

> Of course this variable names is not real

But to do this, `bcrypt` (`Hash::make()`) it does not seem a good idea.

So, i have some questions:

1. How generate a token from string and after check it as `password_hash` and `password_verify`?
2. Or has another better way to solve this case?

Comment: Could you not generate a list of the products you have and compare the selected value with that. If it isn't one of those types throw an exception/ error message?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would validate this using a request.

First use the artisan command

```
php artisan make:request MyRequest
```

Then use this in you request

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
class MyRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'exists:products,name'
        ];
    }

}
```

in your controller make sure you use the request. I like to use dependency injection for this

```
public function myFunction(MyRequest $request)
{
    /*Stuff */
}
```

make sure you declare it at the top of your controller

```
use App\Http\Requests\MyRequest;
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-exists